# How do I fix crashing Application when using Glide

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide, mobile-development

I was following a tutorial on **freeCodeCamp.org** on Youtube about **Android Studio Crash Course**. It was doing well so far until the **RecycleView** part. We used **Glide** to show the images from the internet and for some reason it's not working for me. I commented the **Glide** code and it worked; of course the images didn't show up so I'm sure that the **Glide** code was the problem. Can anyone help me?

Here's the code:

```
Glide.with(context)
.asBitmap()
.load(contacts.get(position).getImgUrl())
.into(holder.image);
```

Here's what LOGCAT says:

```
2020-10-28 22:48:26.776 413-413/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-10-28 22:48:26.776 413-413/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-10-28 22:48:29.441 415-415/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-10-28 22:48:29.441 415-415/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
```

Some more errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerviewexample, PID: 8594
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:669)
        at com.example.recyclerviewexample.ContactsRecViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactsRecViewAdapter.java:74)
        at com.example.recyclerviewexample.ContactsRecViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactsRecViewAdapter.java:26)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:490)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Also here's the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fis26HvvDII&t=35923s at 10:03:50

Comment: show your error log please

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited my question now.

Comment: I don't think this is a Glide issue. I think that contacts.get(position) either has an invalid position or your contact object has no image url. Try logging the the properties of your contact at that position and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The image url are hard coded.
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1053055123193122816/IUwo6l_Q_400x400.jpg
Like this for example

Comment: Oh my, I got it. I'm sorry to bother you guys. I put R.id.image instead of R.id.img.
Thank you guys anyway

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to trap errors in Glide:

```
private RequestListener<Bitmap> requestListener = new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {  
   @Override
   public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
   // todo log exception to central service or something like that

   // important to return false so the error placeholder can be placed
   return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
   // everything worked out, so probably nothing to do
   return false;
 }
};
```

then add it to your Glide build:

```
GlideApp  
.with(context)
  .asBitmap()
  .load(yourImages)
  .listener(requestListener)
  .error(R.drawable.errorImage)
  .into(imageViewPlaceholder);
```

In this way you can debug and find out what is the problem.

Comment: Seems like perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, it still crashes.

Comment: This is a way to tell what is wrong, not fix the crash.